# Not able to access https pages in my server from IE6

Tags: ssl, https, internet-explorer-6

I am not able to access the https pages in my website from IE6. Http requests work fine.

Https pages in a few other websites seems to be working in IE6 without any trouble.

Here is what IE6 says for my website:

```
The page cannot be displayed
... blah blah blah ...
Cannot find server or DNS Error
```

Any ideas how I can go about fixing the issue?

(I tried the `openssl s_client` utility and it says that content negotiation is enabled on my website)

Comment: Is port 443 open? Does the page work in other browsers?

Comment: Yes, the page works in all other major browsers (including ie7, ie8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem and solution is given here: http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/web-browsers/threads/50765

The why is here: http://www.openssl.org/~bodo/tls-cbc.txt

We fixed it by adding the line:

```
options=DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMANTS
```

to the stunnel config file.